# Popover has opacity: 0 on show

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the button from the documentation of Bootstrap 4:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on top
</button>
```

and below it a method:

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    container: 'body',
    trigger: 'click',
  })
})
```

When inspecting the HTML, I can see that there is a new div shown `<div class="popover fade top in"..`
Which is not visible. When inspecting the element, it has a class which hides it:

```css
.fade:not(.show){
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Untoggeling it, shows the popover as intended.
Any clues, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you take note of everything mentioned under https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/popovers/#overview, specifically what libraries and plugins are required?

Comment: Popovers aren't visible by default. It has no opacity it because it doesn't have the "show" class. On click, it toggles this class so it appears/dissapears. Do yo need the popover to be shown on page load?

Comment: @04FS, Yes and I confirm everything is in place. I think it might because I have conflicting CSS libraries that override my usage.

Comment: When inspecting the element, that should show you where the styles come from. If that is one of the bootstrap stylesheets, then it is likely not an issue with any custom CSS outside of that. Anyway, if you need more help - then proper [mre], please, including all the embedding of external resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the selection of classes that are on the popover. As you stated correctly `.fade:not(.show)` kicks in but your classes are `<div class="popover fade top in"..`. So the problem is it uses `.in` instead of `.show`. So i guess there is somewhere a version difference, because i think popovers in **bootstrap 3** used to have `in` whereas **bootstrap 4** uses `show`

Are you setting this maybe manually somewhere using the bootstrap events? Or maybe you imported the wrong version of bootstrap.js?

Comment: Finally, I got an answer. Replaced in with show make dialog visible. Thanks a lot.